# Next Image component with different SrcSet-Images

Tags: image, next.js

I try to change a classic picture-tag with different media-images into the next.js Image components:

Org:

```
 <picture>
    <source media="(min-width:740px)" srcSet={block.imageLandscape.url} />
    <img
      src={block.imagePortrait.url}
      alt={block.imagePortrait.title}
      width={block.imagePortrait.width}
      height={block.imagePortrait.height}
      className={basic.imgFluid}
    ></img>
 </picture>
```

New:

```
 <Image
      src={block.imagePortrait.url}
      alt={block.imagePortrait.title}
      width={2560}
      height={720}
      sizes="(max-width: 739px) 100vw, 740px"
      srcSet={`${block.imageLandscape.url} 2560w, ${block.imagePortrait.url} 740w`}
      className={basic.imgFluid}
  />
```

the next image always take the url from the src, srcSet is not working. What is wrong? thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

The Next.js docs says that all props are passed to the `<img />` tag with exception for `srcSet`. You should use `deviceSizes` instead.

[next-image srcSet docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/components/image#other-props)

[deviceSizes prop documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/components/image#devicesizes)